# Update subset of data in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given the following request.

Please give 7% of the current contacts registered to each of the sales associates to the new sales associate ('Peter').

What I decided to do was to get the total records for each sales associate and calculate 7% of the records.

For example 
David has 200
200/7%  = 14

```
SELECT TOP 14 ContactAssociate
FROM tb_Contact 
WHERE tb_Contact.ContactAssociate = 'David' 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Now, I can select the data but am struggling to update them;
I thought this would do it but no joy.

```
UPDATE tb_Contact
SET ContactAssociate = 'Peter'
IN
(
SELECT TOP 14 ContactAssociate
FROM tb_Contact 
WHERE tb_Contact.ContactAssociate = 'David' 
ORDER BY NEWID()
)
```

Any ideas where, I'm going wrong?
Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PK_Of_tb_Contact - primary key in your tb_Contact table

```
UPDATE tb_Contact
SET ContactAssociate = 'Peter'
where PK_Of_tb_Contact
IN
(
SELECT TOP 14 PK_Of_tb_Contact
FROM tb_Contact 
WHERE tb_Contact.ContactAssociate = 'David' 
ORDER BY NEWID()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE c
SET ContactAssociate = 'Peter'
FROM tb_Contact c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT TOP 14 ContactAssociate FROM tb_Contact 
  WHERE tb_Contact.ContactAssociate = 'David' 
) q ON c.ContactAssociate = q.ContactAssociate
```

If you want to try if you are updating the records you want, you may do this:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM tb_Contact c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT TOP 14 ContactAssociate FROM tb_Contact 
  WHERE tb_Contact.ContactAssociate = 'David' 
) q ON c.ContactAssociate = q.ContactAssociate
```

As you can see, the only change between updates or checks are the lines before the FROM clause.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `TOP 7 PERCENT` or `TOP 7 PERCENT WITH TIES`?

```
DECLARE @sample int
SET @sample = 7

UPDATE tb_Contact
SET ContactAssociate = 'Peter'
where PK_Of_tb_Contact
IN
(
SELECT TOP (@sample) PERCENT PK_Of_tb_Contact
FROM tb_Contact 
WHERE tb_Contact.ContactAssociate = 'David' 
ORDER BY NEWID()
)
```